# SwiftUI why Navigationlink resets my array

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

After clicking NavigationLink button it resets my array value 3 times and says Unable to present. Please file a bug.

Here I select players that I want to use on next view

```
ForEach(viewModel.players) { player in
        let selected = viewModel.selectedIds.contains(player.id)
        PlayerCell(isSelected: selected, player: player, friend: nil)
          .onTapGesture {
            if selected {
              viewModel.selectedIds.remove(player.id)
            } else {
              viewModel.selectedIds.insert(player.id)
            }
            viewModel.selectedPlayers = viewModel.players
              .filter { viewModel.selectedIds.contains($0.id) }
              .map { Player(id: $0.id, playerImageName: $0.playerImageName, playerName: $0.playerName) }
          }
      }
```

Here is my viewModel merged players to I get printed value which players I selected:

```
   var mergedPlayers: [Player] {
    print("SelectedPlayerNames: \(selectedPlayers)")
    return selectedPlayers
  }
```

It prints to console:
SelectedPlayerNames: [Player(id: "A9BCED62-5994-446F-A25A-4107BB1F8510", playerImageName: "girl-4", playerName: "Player 1"), Player(id: "CF870E2E-CC86-4159-96A1-19E22C2050E2", playerImageName: "boy-6", playerName: "Player 2")]

Here is my NavigationLink that move players to next view

```
NavigationLink(
      destination:
        PlayView(viewModel: PlayViewModel(course: viewModel.course, players: viewModel.mergedPlayers)),
      label: {
        PrimaryButton(title: "Start game")
          .padding()
      })
```

After clicking that navigation link it prints to console:

Unable to present. Please file a bug.
Unable to present. Please file a bug.
SelectedPlayerNames: []
Unable to present. Please file a bug.
Game created
Unable to present. Please file a bug.
SelectedPlayerNames: []
Unable to present. Please file a bug.
SelectedPlayerNames: []

Why it resets my SelectedPlayers array?

Comment: Why do you have so much code in the ForEach loop, shouldn’t that logic be handled by the view model?

Comment: Good point there.

Comment: You are also likely using `@ObservedObject var viewModel: YourModel = YourModel()` change that too `@StateObject var viewModel: YourModel = YourModel()` per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)